# Can we compute tree-level amplitudes in string theory using the fundamental domain of $SL(2; \mathbb{C})$?

Tags: string-theory, scattering, conformal-field-theory, gauge-invariance, tachyon

I am not a specialist in string theory. I understand the computation of tree-level string amplitudes (Veneziano or Virasoro-Shapiro), where three variables are fixed using the symmetry $SL(2;\mathbb{C})$. This can be understood as a Faddeev-Popov procedure, where ghosts are introduced and their correlators have to be computed. Now, here and there I hear ppl saying that this is equivalent to restricting the integration limits in the amplitude to the fundamental domain of $SL(2; \mathbb{C})$. Is this true? If yes, could somebody sketch how it would work for, say, the three-point amplitude of tachyons?

Comment: This probably refers to role of SL(2,Z) in one-loop calculations. One loop scattering of strings corresponds to torus (genus one Riemann surface) with marked points (the asymptotic string states). Torus can be represented by a fundamental domain of SL(2,Z)

Comment: I see, so I suppose there is no similar trick (restriction of the domain of integration) at tree level?

Comment: Topologically, tree level scattering of closed strings is a sphere, tree level scattering of open strings is a disk. (The sphere or disk corresponds to the worldsheet of the scattered strings, conformally transformed.) I think the disk is sometimes represented as the complex upper half plane...

Comment: So is it possible you think to restrict the integration domain to the complex upper half plane for the tree level scattering amplitude? Would that be equivalent to having ghosts?